# How to get value from void functions?

Tags: java, try-catch

I have a code currently that have a void function and i have some values within that function that is surrounded by try/catch and i need to get the value.

Any idea how would i be able to extract out the value from try/catch? cannot really change the function to string method.

Below is the code:

```
  protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        if (json != null) {
            Toast.makeText(FindFriends.this, json.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                name = json.getString("name");
                System.out.println(name);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT. added more codes to clarify.**

```
 class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        // JSON parser class
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        private static final String LOGIN_URL = url;

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // here Check for success tag
            try {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("hp", args[0]);
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                if (json != null) {
                    Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                    return json;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: declare global variable at class level and assign value to it and use for further use .. but depends on your requirement

Comment: You could store the value as member and access it in other parts of your class.

Comment: Can plz more specific about your question? You need to read the "name" variable data out the function(onPostExecute) or out side of the try catch.

Comment: Create a static and extract the value to/from it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass an object into the method, then assign your needed value into that object's property

```
class DataObject {
    private String name;
    //getter & setter
    ...
}
```

And:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json, DataObject do) {
    ...
    do.name = json.getString("name");
    ...
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the onPostExecute method as it becomes grey and any message saying 'Method is never used'. I edited my post with more codes to see if it helps in changing your answer

Answer (score 0):

`void` returns.. void, there is no extracting in it. It does something and that's it. You can, however, change it from `void` to `string`. But if that' something you really can't do, than maybe static (global) variables might help? Try:

```
protected static String _Name;
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        if (json != null) {
            Toast.makeText(FindFriends.this, json.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                name = json.getString("name");
                System.out.println(name);
                this._Name = name;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: This is a inner class. Pls see my edited post thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be good or perfect solutions. But will work.

- have an instance variable and get that.
- Add a object parameter to the method and update the object. Ref from caller should give the update.